# Manipulating directories in Java Ant

Tags: java, properties, ant, string-operations

I have an Ant xml file. In this file I want to set two properties based on the current working directory. The current working directory is always of the form `/some/base/dir/SRC/sub/dir`.

The first property must be set to the current working directory. The second property must be set to the part of the current working directory up to `/SRC`.

I can set the first property without any issue using the `PWD` environment variable , but I cannot figure out the second.

```
<property name="my.dir" value="${env.PWD}" />
<property name="src.dir" value="{what do I put here?}" />
```

I've heard this can be done with bash-style string manipulation (e.g. `${PWD%*/SRC}/SRC`) using StringOps, but I cannot find any good examples.

Comment: You could just use `<property name="src.dir" location="${my.dir}/../.."/>`.

Comment: That would work if I knew how many subdirectories were between ${PWD} and .../SRC. but that is not a fixed number :(.

Answer (score 0):

One approach is to use the `<pathconvert>` task, perhaps like this:

```
<property name="my.dir" value="/some/base/dir/SRC/sub/dir"/>

<pathconvert property="src.dir">
  <path path="${my.dir}"/>
  <mapper type="regexp" from="^(.*)/SRC" to="\1" />
</pathconvert>
<echo message="src.dir=${src.dir}" />
```

Which gives:

```
[echo] src.dir=/some/base/dir
```

There are [other mappers available](https://ant.apache.org/manual/Types/mapper.html) which might work better for you than regexp.